# Run capacitor replacement for a fridge

Tags: capacitor

I need to replace the run capacitor on my mini fridge and found a possible replacement.

All specs match except that the original is rated 5 µF, the replacement is rated 6 µF.

Will this difference cause any trouble?

Original specs: 5 µF, 250 VAC, 50/60 Hz, 40/85/21, CBB 65

Comment: Was the 5 uF one rated +-20 % by any chance?

Comment: First of all, want to thank you SO much for your advice & comments. The original Cap was rated at +-5%.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have zero risk of anything going wrong, a like for like replacement is always best. However I would say that 6uF is probably a close enough replacement that it will work just fine. Assuming that the important values (like voltage, ESR etc) are suitable.

Comment: THANK YOU, SO MUCH for your advice & comment.  Many, many thanks. DHSS